# Using LibMan to add Bootstrap 5 to a RazorPages project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Added Bootstrap5 to my `libman.json` and I don't understand what to do next.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "font-awesome@6.0.0",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/font-awesome/"
    },
    {
      "library": "bootstrap@5.1.3",
      "destination": "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is no `bootstrap.min.js`. What am I supposed to do? Do I need to add `boostrap.css` or all four of the `css` files?

```
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />*@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

What about the JS file? I guess it's needed for stuff like modals. Will I need to work out and add dependencies such as jQuery (there's no sign of any jQuery being installed anywhere) -- aren't package managers supposed to do that sort of thing for you? What is the `scss` folder for?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add bootstrap.min.css, the file is there and you can see it if you expand bootstrap.css

[image: bootstrap]